# Display tooltip content in multiple rows

Tags: html, css, vue.js, tailwind-css

In my vue js component, I'm trying to create a custom tool tip text with multiple line of texts.

```
<div class="toolTip">
  Shift ('+i+')
</div>
<div class="hide">
  <div class="w-full">
   '+names[group]+'
  </div>
  <div class="w-full">
   <span class="material-icons">calendar_today</span>03 Mar 2023 - 04 Mar 2023 
  </div>
  <div class="w-full">
   <span class="material-icons">schedule</span> 
   08:00 - 18:00 
  </div> 
  <div class="w-full">
   <span class="material-icons">pending_actions</span>
   Door-to-door travel time: 6 hours
  </div>
</div>
```

This outputs me something like follows,

[image]

But, I want to display each line in a separate row...

Following is my CSS

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
    
.toolTip:hover + .hide {
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px;
    background: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.9);
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -140px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
    
}
```

I'm using tailwind css in my application..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
display: flex;
```

Will try to fit all your content on the same line.

Try:

```
display: inherit;
```

or

```
display: inline;
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using tailwindcss , you can make use of it.

Here you class

```
    display: flex;
    padding: 16px;
    background: rgba(9, 30, 66, 0.9);
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top: -140px;
    text-align: left;
    line-height: 20px;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 14px;
   
}
```

will changes to this `hidden group-hover:flex p-[16px] rounded-[4px] bg-[#091E42] text-left text-white font-normal text-[14px]` simply.

You can use them in following way

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
<div class="group p-4 space-y-3">
<div class="p-[10px] rounded-[4px] bg-[#091E77] text-left text-white font-normal w-56 cursor-pointer ">
  Shift ('+i+')
</div>
<div class="hidden group-hover:flex p-[16px] rounded-[4px] bg-[#091E42] text-left text-white font-normal text-[14px]">
  <div class="w-full">
   '+names[group]+'
  </div>
  <div class="w-full">
   <span class="material-icons">calendar_today</span>03 Mar 2023 - 04 Mar 2023
  </div>
  <div class="w-full">
   <span class="material-icons">schedule</span>
   08:00 - 18:00
  </div>
  <div class="w-full">
   <span class="material-icons">pending_actions</span>
   Door-to-door travel time: 6 hours

  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

> As you hover the blue button, you can see the Tolltip.

You can learn more on `group` over [here](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/hover-focus-and-other-states#styling-based-on-parent-state)